# Arguments in function

Tags: c++

I am a new c++ student and I am trying to make a basic program for kids to learn basic math.  This is a work in progress so some of the code is not done.  I am trying to compile what I have done so far and I am getting an error that says: 47 59    [Error] new declaration 'void add(int, int, std::string, char)' AND 18  5[Error] ambiguates old declaration 'int add(int, int, std::string, char)'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#define over2  "\t\t"
#define over3  "\t\t\t"
#define over4  "\t\t\t\t"
#define down5  "\n\n\n\n\n"
#define down8  "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
#define down10 "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
#define down12 "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"

using namespace std;

int add(int,int,string,char);
int sub();
int multi();
int div();

int main(int argc, char** argv) 


{
    int num1, num2;

    unsigned seed = time(0);
    srand(seed);
    num1 = 1 +rand() % 4;   
    num2 = 1 +rand() % 4;   
//  correctAnswer = (num1+num2);


    cout << "This program is a tool for young kids to learn basic math.\n";
    cout << "Just press any key and the learning will commence!\n";

    system("CLS");

    add(num1, num2, "Addition", '+');
//  addResults(num1+num2);

    return 0;
}

void add(int num1, int num2, string operation, char symbol)
{
    cout << down8;
    cout << over3 << operation << endl;
    cout << over3 << "________\n";
    cout << over3 << setw(3) << num1 << endl;
    cout << over3 << symbol << endl;
    cout << over3 << setw(3) << num2 << endl;
    cout << over3 << "________\n";


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The return types of your `add` method differ in the declaration (`int`) and in the definition (`void`). I think the definition's type should be changed to `int` and make it return the result.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think the problem is in the beginning.
When you define your add function, you write it as `int add(int,int,string,char);`
However, you don't define the variables properly like you do when you actually write the function. Also, in the beginning you define it as int, but you write it as void. The compiler doesn't know what you are trying to do because it thinks there are 2 add functions, one of int type and another void function, which is probably the 18 5[Error] ambiguates old declaration 'int add(int, int, std::string, char)'